# Смешивание двух цветов для фона в CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, псевдоэлемент

Я хочу сложить два цвета один поверх другого. Я сделал это, создав и совмещая два блока, располагая один наверху с непрозрачностью 60%. Интересно, есть ли более простой способ, требующий только одного div с двумя цветами или, может быть, только одного цвета, который представляет собой смесь двух.

Я размещаю здесь свой код. Если вы заметили какие-либо плохие практики, дайте мне знать, пожалуйста. Я очень хочу улучшить свои навыки.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~~~SKY~~~~~~~~~~ */

#sky {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to top, midnightblue, black);
}


/* ~~~~~~~~~~MOON~~~~~~~~~~ */

.moon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#dark-moon {
  background-color: silver;
}

#light-moon {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  background-image: radial-gradient(dimgrey 20%, transparent 16%), radial-gradient(dimgrey 15%, transparent 16%);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
  opacity: 60%;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~~~SEA~~~~~~~~~~ */

#sea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: #48B;
}
```

```html
<div id="sky">
  <div id="dark-moon" class="moon"></div>
  <div id="light-moon" class="moon"></div>
</div>

<div id="sea"></div>
```

Как видите, над серебряной луной золотая. Как я могу получить тот же результат, имея только одну луну?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Mixing two colors for a background in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65219464/7394871) от участника  [@Davide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14170686/davide).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65219464/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сделать это с `0` элементами, используя псевдоэлемент и несколько фонов:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( to top, midnightblue, black);
}

html::before {
  content:"";   
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(192,192,192,0.4) 0 0),
    radial-gradient(dimgrey 20%, transparent 16%), 
    radial-gradient(dimgrey 15%, transparent 16%) 30px 30px,
    goldenrod;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
}

html::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 25vh;
  background: #48B;
}
```

Еще одна интересная идея по большей оптимизации кода:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#48B 0 0) bottom/100% 25vh no-repeat fixed,
   linear-gradient(black,midnightblue);
}

html::before {
  content:"";   
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#48B 0 0) bottom/100% 25vh no-repeat fixed,
    linear-gradient(rgba(192,192,192,0.4) 0 0),
    radial-gradient(dimgrey 20%, transparent 16%) 0    0   /60px 60px, 
    radial-gradient(dimgrey 15%, transparent 16%) 30px 30px/60px 60px,
    goldenrod;
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219644/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>